# detect subdomain and set shared (global) variable in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I've got the following snippet successfully routing subdomain request. I'm looking for a way where I can detect the subdomain and do some quick logic to assign a value to a global variable depending on the subdomain. Where could I do this?

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{username}.murch.co'), function() {
    Route::controller('checkout', 'CheckoutController');
    Route::get('/', 'UserController@getProfile');
});
```

I'd like to do something like

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{username}.murch.co'), function() {
    $var = "dog".$username;
    View::share('var', $var);
    Route::controller('checkout', 'CheckoutController');
    Route::get('/', 'UserController@getProfile');
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you did. And why do you need a global var for?

Comment: for some reason you can't access $username like that. I have no idea why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know how to achieve this is routes.php but I ended up finding a solution using filters

```
 App::before(function($request)
 {
    $urlParts = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    $subdomain = $urlParts[0];
    $userModel = new User;
    $user = $userModel->getUserByUsername($subdomain);
    View::share('user', $user);
 });
```

Comment: Which file i need to put this code, i am using laravel 5.3

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 5.x, you can call it from anywhere - controller, view, etc.

```
Route::current()->parameter('username');
```